# Excel sheet Pre Populated Formulas values not refreshed

Tags: openxml, formulas

I have a requirement where excel file ( i will treat this is an a template) which has a pre populated formulas ( for close to 10k rows), when i populate the dependent column values the formulas calculations are not updated or refreshed. please help me with the same.

The formulas will be populated for 10k rows but while populating the data i may be populating the data just for 100 rows but user can add many more records later so we populate the formulas for 10k rows.

Code below:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using Microsoft.IT.Sales.RelationshipManagement.Segmentation.DataContracts;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {           
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            PopulateExcel("E:\\Formula.xlsx");            
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }

        private static void PopulateExcel(string Path)
        {   
            WorkbookPart WP;
            //WorksheetPart WSP;
            String rId;
            Worksheet WS;
            SheetData StD;
            Row R1;
            Row R2;
            Row R3;
            Cell C1;
            Cell C2;
            Cell C3;
            CellFormula CF;
            CalculationChainPart CP;
            CalculationChain CC;
            CalculationCell CCell;
            Workbook Workbook;
            Sheet ss;
            Sheet Sheet;

            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Path, true))
            {
                // Get the SharedStringTablePart. If it does not exist, create a new one.
                WP = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart;
                var wsp = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault(); //.ElementAt(sheetnumber);
                SheetData sheetData = wsp.Worksheet.Descendants<SheetData>().LastOrDefault();

                R1 = GetRow(sheetData, 2);
                C1 = new Cell();
                SetCell(C1, "A1", 1);
                sheetData.Append(R1);

                R1.Append(C1);

                C2 = new Cell();
                SetCell(C2, "B1", 2);

                R1.Append(C2);    

                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;
                wsp.Worksheet.Save();

                // Close the document.
                spreadSheet.Close();
            }   
        }

        private static Row GetRow(SheetData wsData, UInt32 rowIndex)
        {
            var row = wsData.Elements<Row>().
            Where(r => r.RowIndex.Value == rowIndex).FirstOrDefault();
            if (row == null)
            {
                row = new Row();
                row.RowIndex = rowIndex;
                wsData.Append(row);
            }
            return row;
        }
        private static void SetCell(Cell cell, string Reference, int Value)
        {
            cell.CellReference = Reference;
            cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue();
            cell.CellValue.Text = Value.ToString();

        }    
    }
}
```

Please help me with the code.

Comment: Is your Calculation Mode of the excel workbook set to manual?

Comment: HI
Yes i have tried updating this, but that didnt help.

Thank you.